# XML HTTP GET Request Fails

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing a pure JS GET request, to my localhost (don't worry I tested POST and that works), I can access all the database and everything else but the GET request won't work. My JS code is shown below:

```
functtion getSessionKey() {
    XMLHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();

    XMLHTTP.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/projects/To-Do-App/api/sessionData/sessionKey.php", true);

    XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (XMLHTTP.readyState == 4) {
            alert(XMLHTTP.responseText);
        }
    }
    XMLHTTP.send(null);
}
```

In the PHP file I have the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['sessionKey']) && !empty(trim($_SESSION['sessionKey']))) {
    echo htmlspecialchars(trim($_SESSION['sessionKey']));
}
?>
```

The POST requests all work and insert into the database, but the GET request seem to stop all the JS code below it from working. Any ideas why? I have tried changing the last parameter true/false. Also I am trying to make it for a mobile application through  Intel XDK so I using JS and PHP if that helps. Please no jQuery solutions as that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It does not work... Well what does the server return?

Comment: Did you check `XMLHTTP.status` ?

Comment: @nquocnghia I can't even get that as all the code just freezes and I just tried it and the alert(); doesn't even show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the content type

```
var XMLHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
...
```

and try to replace

```
XMLHTTP.send(null);
```

with

```
XMLHTTP.send();
```

Comment: Hm, it looks ok, have you tried to use var in front of your first XMLHHTP?

Comment: Yep, still doesn't work, this is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send a `null` in with the `.send()` Make it

`XMLHttp.send()`

Comment: Check console. I'm guessing you'll have an error dealing with [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) because you are using `http://` and declaring the full link. Try using a local path to where you want to go

Comment: I'm using HTTP and the POST works. But I tried using local path still doesn't work, and as for the console, I can't, seeing as I'm doing JS mobile development.